# How can I make a regex for hostnames with format xxxNN.xxxNNN

Tags: regex

I need to figure out how to make a regex that matches the following format. It would be two to three letters followed by two to three numbers followed by a . with three letters and three numbers.

matching hosts would be rr01.tdw301 or www101.red102   xxx000.xxx000 or xx00.xxx000. It should not be case sensitive.

Comment: Step 1 in figuring it out: Learning regexes: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
/[a-zA-Z]{2,3}\d{2,3}\.[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{3}/
```

Breakdown:

```
[a-zA-Z]{2,3}         # match 2 or 3 letters of either case
\d{2,3}               # match 2 or 3 digits
\.                    # match a period (.)
[a-zA-Z]{3}           # match exactly 3 letters of either case
\d{3}                 # match exactly 3 digits
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/aQ4rI5

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple:

```
[a-z]{2,3}\d{2,3}\.[a-z]{3}\d{3}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/vGlecxwbpJQB2RW2)

How you set it as case-insensitive depends on the language. In most languages, you can do either this:

```
(?i)[a-z]{2,3}\d{2,3}\.[a-z]{3}\d{3}
```

or this:

```
/[a-z]{2,3}\d{2,3}\.[a-z]{3}\d{3}/i
```